# i am making tiny language

Tags: haskell, logging

i am making tiny language. Let E be a tiny programming language that supports the declaration of arithmetic expressions and equality comparison on integers.

given the following data type E:

```
data E = IntLit Int
   | BoolLit Bool
   | Plus E E
   | Minus E E
   | Multiplies E E
   | Exponentiate E E
   | Equals E E
     deriving (Eq, Show)
```

here is my code with above data it is working all of these.

```
data E = IntLit Int
   | BoolLit Bool
   | Plus E E
   | Minus E E
   | Multiplies E E
   | Divides E E
   | Equals E E
   | log2Sim E E        
     deriving (Eq, Show)
eval :: E -> E
eval c@(IntLit i) = c
eval c@(BoolLit b) = c
eval (Plus a b) = plus (eval a) (eval b)
eval (Minus a b) = minus (eval a) (eval b)
eval (Multiplies a b) = multiplies (eval a) (eval b)
eval (Divides a b) = divides (eval a) (eval b)
eval (Equals a b) = equals (eval a) (eval b)

log2Sim :: E -> E
log2sim  = case (eval x) of 
  IntLit i -> IntLit (logBase 2 i)
  x1 -> "type error: can't take the log of a non-IntLit-valued   expresstio" ++ show x1

plus (IntLit i) (IntLit j) = IntLit $ i + j
plus _ _ = error "Type error in addition"

minus (IntLit i) (IntLit j) = IntLit $ i - j
minus _ _ = error "Type error in subtraction"

multiplies (IntLit i) (IntLit j) = IntLit $ i * j
multiplies _ _ = error "Type error in multiplication"

divides (IntLit i) (IntLit j) = IntLit $ i `div` j
divides _ _ = error "Type error in division"

equals (IntLit i) (IntLit j) = BoolLit $ i == j
equals (BoolLit a) (BoolLit b) = BoolLit $ a == b
equals _ _ = error "Type error in equals"
```

when i compiled it, there are some errors.
what error is this?

```
A3.hs:56:7:
Couldn't match expected type `E' against inferred type `[Char]'
In the expression:
      "type error: can't take the lof of a non-IntLit-valued expression: "
    ++
      show x1
In a case alternative:
    x1
      -> "type error: can't take the lof of a non-IntLit-valued expression: "
       ++
         show x1
In the expression:
    case (eval x) of
      IntLit i -> IntLit (logBase 2 i)
      x1
        -> "type error: can't take the lof of a non-IntLit-valued expression: "
         ++
           show x1
```

Comment: The code at the proposed duplicate ([log2Sim For a Tiny Language](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35805098/791604)) has the same type error as in this question, so it does not answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

There are many problems in your code:

1. All constructors must start with an upper-case letter. So `data E = ... | log2Sim E E` is incorrect. You also probably just want one `E`, hence for example `data E = ... | Log E` would fix both these problems.
2. You declared `log2Sim` but defined `log2sim` (notice the difference in capitalization). You also forgot to write the argument `x` to the left of the `=` in the definition. Fix both problems by writing

   ```
   log2Sim x = ...
   ```
3. Strings are not valid expressions of type `E`. You probably wanted to follow the pattern in the rest of your code by calling `error` to turn your error string into an `E`. Thus:

   ```
   x1 -> error $ "type error: can't take the log of a non-IntLit-valued   expresstio" ++ show x1
   ```
4. `logBase` operates on `Floating`-point numbers, and `Int` is not one. There's a few ways to fix this, but the shortest distance between here and there is to convert to a `Double` and back. For example:

   ```
   IntLit i -> IntLit . floor . logBase 2 . fromIntegral $ i
   ```

This is enough to make your code compile, though there may be other problems.